# MC705C8ACPE chip

Tags: microcontroller, programming, dip

I have a few old mc705c8acpe chips and I would like to know how to program and use them. I would like to control an lcd display, (20x4) with them. All I could find about them was they are programmable microcotrollers. Nothing else. I would like to program it with my computer. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 4):

The full (or an alternate) part number may be MC68HC705C8 - I used those in a project back in 1995.

Datasheets, application notes and the 6805 Reference manual and other information are available from NXP at https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/legacy-mcu-mpus/8-bit-legacy-mcus/microcontroller:68HC705C8A?tab=Documentation_Tab